# How do I make my coin seeds?

Tags: blockchain

I want to add DNS seeds – like bitcoin – to my alt-coin. Is bitcoins generate-seeds.py and makeseeds.py the scripts to register DNS-seed ips?

Answer (score 1):

> Is bitcoins generate-seeds.py and makeseeds.py the scripts to register DNS-seed ips?

No, not at all. Those scripts are for creating the hardcoded seed nodes list which is retrieved from an existing DNS seeder.

To add a DNS seeder, you would need to add it to the list of DNS seeders in [src/chainparams.cpp](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/chainparams.cpp#L123). Furthermore, you need to have a running DNS seeder which requires special software. One such is https://github.com/sipa/bitcoin-seeder.